# Is there an optimal way to round a numpy array to a specific array?

Tags: python, arrays, rounding

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mG71.png)

I'm currently using this snippet for such operation:

```
Limits=Dataset[0:len(Dataset)-1]+(Dataset[1:len(Dataset)]-Dataset[0:len(Dataset)-1])/2

def RoundtoList(Data):
  Data[Data<=Limits[0]]=Dataset[0]
  for r in range(len(Limits)-1):
    Data[(Limits[r]<Data) & (Data<=Limits[r+1])]=Dataset[r+1]
  Data[Limits[len(Limits)-1]<Data]=Dataset[len(Limits)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
input_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

def round_to_closest(val, rounding_points=[2, 5, 8]):
    
    closest_point_index = np.argmin(abs(val - np.array(rounding_points)))
    
    return rounding_points[closest_point_index]

list(map(round_to_closest, input_array))
```

Output:

```
[2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8, 8]
```